# Can I export constructors along with a type alias?

Tags: haskell

I have a data type `data Foo a b = Bar a b` that I use internally in a library.

I also have an alias for one of its more common concrete forms: `type Bar = Foo Int Int`.

Is there a way to export the `Bar` type, but not the `Foo` type from my library?

I'd like to do:

```
module Quux (
    Bar(Bar)
  ) where
```

But when I attempt this I get the error:

```
The export item ‘Bar(Bar)’
attempts to export constructors or class methods that are not visible here
```

The below would work, except I'd rather not export the `Foo` type at all:

```
module Quux (
    Bar
  , Foo(..)
  ) where
```

Comment: If I may ask, what mistake are you trying to prevent by this? What's the danger of a user creating a `Foo Float Float` value? If you want to prevent the code breaking if the internal structure of `Foo` changes, just export the specialized constructor as a separate function.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to prevent mistakes with this, but to create a module that's a nice entry point to a library. Since probably 95% of users won't ever need to import anything other than the entry module I don't want them to see unnecessarily complicated types if I can avoid it.

Comment: @seagreen: That's a laudable goal, but if they're using `Bar` in their own functions, the inferred type they get will involve `Foo`, even if it infers to `Foo Int Int`.  Exporting a smart constructor `bar :: Int -> Int -> Bar` will avoid that, although you lose pattern matching (you'd have to expose a deconstructor for that; pattern synonyms can't have types yet).  So make sure this does help like you want it to! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *isn't* possible in Haskell 2010, but *is* possible in GHC.

**In Haskell 2010**, you can only export constructors as part of a data type:

> Data constructors cannot be named in export lists except as subordinate names [the `Cᵢ` in `T(C₁,C₂)`], because they cannot otherwise be distinguished from type constructors.  [[Haskell 2010 Report, §5.2 "Export Lists", #2]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2)

**In GHC** ([version 7.8 or later](https://damianfral.github.io/ghcaniuse/)), however, you can use the `PatternSynonyms` language extension to accomplish this: with that turned on, you can qualify constructors in export lists with `pattern`.  So, for instance, your desired example would be

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

module Quux (Bar, pattern Bar) where

data Foo a b = Bar a b
type Bar = Foo Int Int
```

The `pattern Bar` in the export list specifies the constructor, and the unadorned `Bar` specifies the type synonym.

In addition, if you think the unadorned `Bar` is confusing/ambiguous, you can use the `ExplicitNamespaces` extension (in version 7.6 or later) to enable prefixing type constructors with `type`, similarly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitNamespaces, PatternSynonyms #-}

module Quux (type Bar, pattern Bar) where

data Foo a b = Bar a b
type Bar = Foo Int Int
```

From the documentation, about exporting constructors with `pattern`:

> [W]ith `-XPatternSynonyms` you can prefix the name of a data constructor in an import or export list with the keyword `pattern`, to allow the import or export of a data constructor without its parent type constructor [[GHC 7.10 Users Manual, §7.3.26.4 "Explicit namespaces in import/export"]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#explicit-namespaces)

and

> You may also use the `pattern` keyword in an import/export specification to import or export an ordinary data constructor.  For example:
>
> ```
> import Data.Maybe( pattern Just )
> ```
>
> would bring into scope the data constructor `Just` from the `Maybe` type, without also bringing the type constructor `Maybe` into scope.  [[GHC 7.10 Users Manual, §7.3.9.2 "Import and export of pattern synonyms"]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#patsyn-impexp)

Plus, for exporting types with `type`:

> The `-XExplicitNamespaces` extension allows you to prefix the name of a type constructor in an import or export list with "`type`" to disambiguate… [[GHC 7.10 Users Manual, §7.3.26.4 "Explicit namespaces in import/export"]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#explicit-namespaces)

---

That said, I am inclined to agree with [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617208/237428) here – there's a reason the report disallows this.  Type signatures that are impossible to write down – e.g., `Bar :: a -> b -> Quux.Foo a b` – are a bit maddening.  But the type synonym  does help with that; just make sure your documentation is *thorough* :-)

Comment: I appreciate the words of caution (from both you and @dfeuer). I'm not sure why, but I was imagining that the end result would be `Bar :: a -> b -> Bar` (using the type alias since that's in scope). It's not though, what actually gets shown is what you wrote: `Bar :: a -> b -> Quux.Foo`.


EDIT: Finished half-written comment, I hit enter hoping for a newline:(

Comment: Anyway for those reasons I will definitely go with one of the counter-suggestions in this thread instead of the original idea. And thanks for explaining PatternSynonyms, perhaps I'll run into a situation where I should use them someday!

Answer (score 2):

You can export `Bar` type simply by `module Quux (Bar) where ...`, though you will not be able to *construct* any `Bar`s.

If you also need the constructor, you may use similar technique to [**smart constructors**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors), that is create a helper functions which creates `Bar`s and export that one:

```
module Quux (Bar, bar) where

data Foo a b = Foo a b
type Bar = Foo Int Int

bar :: Int -> Int -> Bar
bar = Foo
```

then

```
\> let b = bar 1 2
\> :type b
b :: Bar
\> let f = Foo 1 2

<interactive>:9:9: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Foo’
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this? No, don't bother answering. **Don't do this.** Whatever you think it will accomplish, it will not. What you *can* do, however, is use a newtype (note that I changed the names a bit):

```
newtype Bar = _Bar (Foo Int Int)
data Foo a b = Foo a b
```

Now you can use *pattern synonyms* to make `Bar` user-friendly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

module Whatever (Bar, pattern Bar)
pattern Bar a b = _Bar (Foo a b)
```

There's a bit of weirdness having to use the `pattern` keyword to import the synonym, but oh well. Unlike your approach, the end user has access to a proper first-class type and not just a synonym. And they can't see anything of `Foo`.

Comment: You probably want this `pattern Bar a b = _Bar a b` to actually be `pattern Bar a b = _Bar (Foo a b)`.