# Can I import a type synonym's data constructors without using the ViewPatterns GHC extension?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a module A and B which both export the `Event` type. Module C defines a type synonym to module A's `Event`, calling it `InputEvent`.

I then consume both module B and module C in a module D:

```
module D where

import B (Event)
import C (InputEvent)
```

However, if I try to import `InputEvent`'s type constructors (say, `MakeEvent`), I get the error:

```
Module
‘C’
does not export
‘InputEvent(MakeEvent)’
```

This could be solved by using the ViewPatterns GHC extension and exporting an alias to MakeEvent from module C:

```
makeEvent = MakeEvent
```

However, is there a way of importing the MakeEvent data constructor without using the ViewPatterns extension?

Comment: Type synonyms do not have constructors, so naturally importing the constructors of a type synonym will fail. Import the constructors from whichever module exports them: `import {B/C} (Event(MakeEvent))`. Pattern syns won't really help here - the `MakeEvent` constructor would clash with the `MakeEvent` pattern, so you would have to import them qualified. Furthermore, you do not need any such aliases - simply re-export `MakeEvent` from module `C`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616041/can-i-export-constructors-along-with-a-type-alias

Answer (score 2):

Don't use type synonyms to enforce abstraction barriers, except possibly small, private ones. They're no good at it. If you want to hide `Event`, use a newtype and pattern synonyms.

Comment: I don't want to hide `Event`. Module C just re-exports it for convenience (so that I don't have to use qualified imports), as it's purpose it to allow module A and B to interoperate. I would be happy exporting just the data constructors from module A, except I can't without exporting the type constructor, which causes an ambiguous reference in module D. Maybe the best thing to do is scrap the type alias and just use qualified imports.

Comment: @CameronMartin, that sounds like a good plan to me. It'd be nice if you could import the type qualified but its constructors unqualified. As it is, your best bet may be a qualified import along with local bidirectional pattern synonyms.