# Import a data constructor without importing the type

Tags: haskell, import

`numeric-prelude` does this thing where every data type is named `T` and every type-class is named `C`.  For the sake of... consistency, I suppose I'll play along:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module Number.SqrtRatio (T(..), ratioPart) where

import qualified Number.Ratio as Ratio
import Number.Ratio ((:%))

import qualified Algebra.Ring as Ring
import NumericPrelude.Base

-- | A number whose square is rational, canonicalized as a rational
--   times the square root of a squarefree integer.
data T x = T {
    numerator :: !x,
    denominator :: !x,
    rootNum :: !x
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

ratioPart :: T x -> Ratio.T x
ratioPart (T n d _) = n :% d

fromRatio :: (Ring.C x) => Ratio.T x -> T x
fromRatio (n :% d) = T n d Ring.one
```

`ghc` is not impressed:

```
Number/SqrtRatio.hs:5:22:
    In module ‘Number.Ratio’:
      ‘(:%)’ is a data constructor of ‘T’
    To import it use
      ‘import’ Number.Ratio( T( (:%) ) )
    or
      ‘import’ Number.Ratio( T(..) )
```

---

Sure thing buddy, I can comply:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module Number.SqrtRatio (T, ratioPart) where

import qualified Number.Ratio as Ratio
import Number.Ratio (T((:%)))
--       newly added ^
```

...but this also ends up importing `Ratio.T`, which conflicts with my `T`!

```
ratioPart :: T x -> Ratio.T x
{-           ^-- Ambiguous occurrence ‘T’
    It could refer to either ‘Number.SqrtRatio.T’,
                             defined at Number/SqrtRatio.hs:11:1
                          or ‘Number.Ratio.T’,
                             imported from ‘Number.Ratio’ at Number/SqrtRatio.hs:5:22-28
-}
```

---

Alright, so how about `import Number.Ratio (T((:%))) hiding T`?

```
Number/SqrtRatio.hs:5:31: parse error on input ‘hiding’
```

I'm at a bit of a loss, gaise. :/

Comment: Ah, yeah. I quite wish Henning stopped insisting on this naming convention. As someone jokingly said: _he likes to name all his data types after himself_ (**T**hielemann)... Which is not to say I don't respect and trust his choices: in a way it does make sense to use modules as the primary naming hierarchy. But since nobody else does this anyway, you can hardly hope to ever get this really consistent. And in some cases it just really doesn't work well, like the one you have here. Not to speak of documentation readability. Upshot: _don't_ call your types `T`.

Comment: It's certainly not a good sign when the first thing I have to click on every Haddock page is [the source link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.2/docs/src/Number-Ratio.html)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I do somewhat feel for his cause though, as it is certainly possible to pull this off nicely in a language with a [better](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) [module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Error.html) [system](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html).  But such is not Haskell.

Comment: [I answered a related Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35617742/237428) about *exports* a little while back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out there *is* a proper way to do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, PatternSynonyms #-}
module Number.SqrtRatio (T(..), ratioPart) where

import qualified Number.Ratio as Ratio
import Number.Ratio (pattern (:%))
```

Note that I've used the `-XPatternSynonyms` extension not to actually define any pattern synonym, just to enable the `pattern` keyword so it's clear I want to import the *value constructor* `:%` alone.

Comment: Impressive find!  All documentation I can find on this feature only explicitly covers the case where the constructor in question is declared using `pattern` in its originating module (which `(:%)` is not); but it makes sense that this would work for the sake of allowing an exported constructor to be replaced with a synonym transparently.

Answer (score 2):

My current solution, discovered moments before posting:

- Give up on trying to import `(:%)`.
- Keep the qualified import.
- Change `:%` to `Ratio.:%` everywhere (patterns and expressions).

Result:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module Number.SqrtRatio (T(..), ratioPart) where

import qualified Number.Ratio as Ratio

import qualified Algebra.Ring as Ring
import NumericPrelude.Base

-- | A number whose square is rational, canonicalized as a rational
--   times the square root of a squarefree integer.
data T x = T {
    numerator :: !x,
    denominator :: !x,
    rootNum :: !x
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

ratioPart :: T x -> Ratio.T x
ratioPart (T n d _) = n Ratio.:% d

fromRatio :: (Ring.C x) => Ratio.T x -> T x
fromRatio (n Ratio.:% d) = T n d Ring.one
```

Ugly.

Comment: You could also define a local synonym `(%) = (Ratio.:%)`

Comment: @luqui that may work for expressions, but how about the patterns?  I'm not familiar with any way to alias a data constructor

Comment: @ExpHP `pattern x :% y = x Ratio.:% y`, using the `PatternSynonyms` extension.

Comment: Yeah, a pattern synonym would be possible, but... this really feels wrong. You need to re-declare fixity, it's questionable if you should give it a type signature (which then would need syncing in case the exported type changes)...

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree that this feels like an oversight on the part of the Committee. There's no reason for `import Number.Ratio ((:%))` not to work.

Comment: @DanielWagner: why yes, there is a reason: you need some way to distinguish type-level and value-level names in the import list. Of course this problem is most typically encountered with `newtypes` whose constructor is named the same as the type, but you could also have `data (:%) a b = a :% b`. Then `import Number.Ratio ((:%))` would obviously only import `(:%) :: * -> * -> *`, not `(:%) :: a -> b -> a:%b`. But I agree that there should be some syntax to import constructors alone. `import Number.Ratio (pattern (:%))` would be a natural choice.

Comment: @DanielWagner wait, _this works_ actually! See my answer.